# what mechanism is preventing divs from fully occupying their parent's width?

Tags: html, css, dom, parent-child

```
  <div class="apg apg-text column-dir" data-image-mode="original_mouse" data-mask-effect="disabled" data-mouseover-effect="fade_both" data-title-align="middle-center" style="min-height: 403px;">
        <div class="post-9 apg-post apg-post-text" data-post-id="9" width="1000px">
            <a class="apg-grid-item" href="http://victorbartis.ro/wordpress/project/ambasada-iubirii" width="1000px">
                <div class="post-thumbnail" data-image-width="60">
                    <img src="http://victorbartis.ro/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/T1.jpg" style="top: 353px; left: 1014.5px; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
                </div>
                <div class="apg-post-title" width="1000px">
                    <div class="title" data-font="font_iz9ovceku" width="100%" display="inline-block">
                        <p class="calupstanga">AMBASADA IUBIRII </p>
                        <p class="calupmijloc">&nbsp;</p>
                        <p class="calupdreapta"> undeva in oras</p>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `width=` and `display=` attributes were placed there manually be me attempting to cause the inner elements match the outermost element width.
Tried multiple values like `auto`, `100%`, `1000`, `1000px`, checked the `margin` and `padding` attributes to be 0. I am guessing some other elements' attributes are getting in the way. Any tips?

Comment: simply because there is no such *width* on HTML, you need to set width using CSS. Same thing with display .. you need to read more about how CSS/HTML works

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh... :). So my only chance is CSS, nothing equivalent in HTML ? You could turn that into an answer.

Comment: Yes you *need* to use CSS because this is the purpose of CSS (styling) and not the purpose of HTML (only for markup). IMHO, I don't think it deserve adding an answer because this is the basic usage of HTML/CSS that we may learn on any online tutorial. It won't add useful information to SO